# Bizarre Objective-C threading

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

I've inherited a codebase for an iOS project and I wonder what the point of this code is:

```
  -(void) someMethod {
      FMDatabaseQueue *dbQueue = self.db;
   // unimportant stuff
  [Async series:@[
      ^(successBlock success, failureBlock failure) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
          [dbQueue inDatabase:^(FMDatabase *db) {
                // do database stuff
          }];
        });
      },
      ^(successBlock success, failureBlock failure) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
          [dbQueue inDatabase:^(FMDatabase *db) {
                // do other database stuff
          }];
        });
      }
  ];    
}
```

Is there any reason to code something like this?

My reading is that the `Async` and the `dispatch_async()` back to the main thread makes the threading pointless.

Comment: It does not make it pointless: Async might execute some code in the background, then call the completion block which does something in the main thread. Whatever Async does might take a substantial amount of time...

Answer (score 1):

The code is strange, but not because of this. The method `+series` probably does something in background (network, computation, $whatever) and then calls the series blocks. The execution of that blocks doesn't seem to be guaranteed on the main thread. But `+series` cannot know, whether they have to be executed on the main thread. (Maybe there is additional computation that should be done in background. Maybe the blocks are executed parallel.)

So, if there is something done, which has to be done on the main thread, you need another `dispatch_async()`.

But yes: You get such constellations, when people try to do everything using blocks without thinking about the need. I do not know, why that happens, but using blocks many coders try to over-engineer their code.

Comment: amen to the but yes part :D

Comment: A little more info: 'Async' is cocoapod described by the author as:"a set of functions for working with asynchronous blocks in Objective-C." '+series' ensures the blocks are executed in the order they appear in the array. I don't believe 'Async' does anything except asynchronously queue the blocks.

Comment: When I see code that has a class method for doing a simple, independent feature, most of the time I close the window. Don't the author know that there are still functions in Objective-C? Neither classes nor class objects are modules. They are types and objects.

Comment: @Twinkle-Toes The class method `series` ensures that (asynchronous) blocks are called in order and the next block is only called when the previous one finished successfully (which presumably requires to call the completion handler). So, it's a bit more than just queueing the blocks. There are more elegant approaches to accomplish the same task, though. (see [Futures and promises](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises))